Why is the output not stable in the given circuit?
I have constructed an audio amplifier using a TIP 127 pair in class A type (circuit below). The output sound (power) keeps decreasing as time passes and is not stable. This is also measured by a voltmeter (V) across the speaker. Why is the voltage/current not stable across the output?


Edit:
For TIP 127
Hfe DC current gain - Ic = 3A Vce= 3V , power dissipation - Tcase ≤ 25deg - 65W , Tamb ≤ 25deg - 2W

What is the power dissipation in the transistors?  What is Hfe (beta) at those power (temperature) levels?

From datasheet: Hfe DC current gain -Ic = 3A Vce= 3V  and  power dissipation - Tcase ≤ 25deg. 65W , Tamb ≤ 25deg. 2W

@RajeshR please update the question ... the information does not belong in a comment

Next time you draw this circuit, please follow the convention of positive voltage on top and voltage dropping as you go down the page.  Currently everything is upside down.

Biasing through a speaker might not be a good idea ...

You have two Darlington transistors that you connected as in Darlington configuration and then used as a common collector amplifier with a 5 V supply. This gives you a ridiculous amount of current gain but not a lot of voltage to do much with it.
This gives you four base-emitter junctions between input and output, which will drop around 2 V with no signal according to my simulation results. A common collector amplifier has a voltage gain of less than 1, so whatever you want the voltage to be at the load you need to put more than that into the input.
You marked the speaker as 5 W, but didn't include it's impedance which is the most important parameter you need to know, all 5 W tells you is that if you put much more than that into it you will burn it out, it doesn't tell you anything about how it will work in the circuit, for example an 8 Ω speaker is going to give you much different results than a 4 Ω speaker.
You also don't give any information on the driving signal. This would need to be at least a few volts to overcome the voltage drop of the transistors. Even then it's likely to be distorted.
There's a single resistor for bias, that's not going to be stable at all and any temperature change is going to change the biasing quite a bit. The base-emitter voltage is temperature dependent, as the transistors warm up this voltage drops which allows more current heating them up more, and worst case you get a run-away situation and the transistors burn up. This is probably what's causing the change you see over time. Also, the speaker is not AC coupled, so it will have a DC bias on it which will offset the speaker cone.
All that said, this is a terrible design, it looks like one of those things you'd see in a scam Youtube video. You would be better off finding a better design than trying to make this one do anything useful.

What can be changed in biasing?

Don't change the biassing, change the entire circuit.

"This gives you four base-emitter junctions between input and output", why are there four?

@a360pilot Each Darlington transistor has two, and this is two Darlingtons in series, so four.

@RajeshR  I just updated my answer to add that the speaker will have a DC bias on it. That's not a good thing. The speaker cone is supposed to move back and forth from it's default center position, DC on the coil offsets the cone so it can't move over it's entire range and tends to hit against one extreme causing distortion and possibly damage. The way to fix that is use a transformer, which for the correct kind is probably going to cost more than building a push-pull amplifier.

@Godjihyo Thank you for your suggestion

I tried in CE configuration, it sounds more, but vey low fidelity.
